# Convergence of a complex series on the boundary and the rate of the function growth

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm interested in conditions on the coefficients of the series
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n\label{1}\tag{$\ast$}
$$
with the convergence radius $0<R<\infty$ to guarantee the convergence of the series to $f(z)$ at some point or arc on the circircumference $|z|=R$. Examples like $(1-z)^{-n}$ seem to indicate that the function's rate of growth at the boundary is connected with the rate of coefficients' growth. From the other hand function
$$
\log (1+z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}n
$$
has a convergent series on the circle $|z|=1$  except the point $z=1$.

Denote $M_f(r)=\max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|$.

**Question:** if $M_f$ grows no faster than logarithmically, i.e.
$$
\limsup_{r\to R-0}\frac{M_f(r)}{|\log(R-r)|}<\infty
$$
and on some arc $A\subset \{|z|=R\}$ function $f$ is smooth enough (or analytic if required), does it follow that the series \eqref{1} converges to $f$ on $A$?

Also does some statement like this holds: if $M_f$ grows slower than logarithmically then in fact $f$ is bounded in the circle $|z|<R$? And if $f$ is smooth on an arc then the series converges there?

Comment: Hmmm... what I know If that $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leq \log \lvert z \rvert$ in $\mathbb{C}$ and $f$ ist entire, then $f$ is constant.

Comment: @Meowdog The assumption deals with the estimate in the area of convergence $ |z|<R< \infty.$ Entire functions are excluded.

Comment: I honestly don't think you'll get anywhere good with what you're asking... I see quite a lot of errors, such as what you say is a circle but with the equation of a circumference; or that the series doesn't represent $\log{z}$ (can't center $\log{z}$ at $z=0$). Or the relationship between Taylor Series' region of convergence and the region where the function is holomorphic. I hope this helps to improve what you need to study and I hope you could ask again later with that new info!

Comment: @Luciano thanks, fixed.

Comment: Note that if you fix any positive increasing function on $(0,1)$ say st $\phi(r) \to \infty, r \to 1^-$ you can get $a_n>0, \sum_{k \le n}a_k=\phi(1-1/n)$ and if in particular $\phi(1-1/m) \le Cm^r$ for some fixed $r$, $\sum a_nz^n$ has convergence radius $1$ and grows as fast $\phi$ at the boundary, so without extra conditions there is no "order of growth low enough" implies bounded result

Comment: even more is true as one can construct analytic functions in the disc with maximum modulus increasing as slowly as we want to infinity, but st they do not have radial limits on any set of positive measure on the unit circle; for the other kinds of question (about the function having smooth/analytic extension to an arc implying convergence of the series there), one needs to look at Tauberian theorems where results depend more of the "shape" of $a_n$ rather than the growth properties of $f$ per se